# Adding items into an array which has some items determined VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

This thing is hard to explain, but easier to see. I'm trying to code a dynamic use for a quertytable from access into Excel. That way users can select which file, table, properties and the date filter they want to get on their query.

This is how will the excel look to manage the query (can be changed, but can handle that):

[image: Excel]

This is the code when I'm recording the macro while doing that stuff:

```
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=Z:\Informes de actividad\BBDD\2017\BBDD_ADIF_2017.accdb;DefaultDir=Z:\Informes de actividad\BBDD\201" _
        ), Array("7;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT PREVISIONES.Centro, PREVISIONES.`Skill Nombre`, PREVISIONES.Fecha, PREVISIONES.Tramo, PREVISIONES.`Prevision Recibidas Cliente`, PREVISIONES.`Prevision Atento`, PREVISIONES.`Prevision Recibidas`, PREVISI" _
        , _
        "ONES.`Prevision Atendidas`, PREVISIONES.`Prevision TMO`, PREVISIONES.`Prevision de Ocupacion s/Requeridos`, PREVISIONES.`Prevision de Ocupacion s/Programados`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `Z:\Informes de actividad\BBDD\2017" _
        , _
        "\BBDD_ADIF_2017.accdb`.PREVISIONES PREVISIONES" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (PREVISIONES.Fecha>{ts '2017-02-01 00:00:00'} And PREVISIONES.Fecha<{ts '2017-03-01 00:00:00'})" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Tabla_Consulta_desde_MS_Access_Database"
    End With
End Sub
```

And this is what I did to get it dynamic:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim QT As QueryTable, wsPr As Worksheet, Año As String, Ruta As String, Archivo As String, Tabla As String, _
    FechaInicio As Date, FechaFin As Date, TablaPropiedades As String, CPropiedades As Collection, i As Integer, _
    Propiedades As String

    Set wsPr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Previsiones")
    Set CPropiedades = New Collection
    Año = "2017"
    Ruta = "Z:\Informes de actividad\BBDD\" & Año
    Tabla = "BBDD_ADIF_2017"
    Archivo = "\" & Tabla & ".accdb"
    TablaPropiedades = "PREVISIONES"
    FechaInicio = Sheets("Hoja69").Range("C2").Value
    FechaFin = Sheets("Hoja69").Range("C3").Value


    For i = 0 To 10
        CPropiedades.Add (TablaPropiedades & "." & Sheets("Hoja69").Cells(i + 2, 2).Value)
    Next i
    For i = 0 To CPropiedades.Count - 1
        If i = 0 Then Propiedades = " " & CPropiedades(i + 1)
        If i <> 0 And i <> CPropiedades.Count Then Propiedades = Propiedades & ", " & CPropiedades(i + 1)
        If i = CPropiedades.Count Then Propiedades = ", " & Propiedades + CPropiedades(i + 1)
    Next i



    With wsPr.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & Ruta + Archivo & ";DefaultDir=" & Ruta) _
        , Array("DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), _
        Destination:=wsPr.Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

        .CommandText = Array("SELECT " & Propiedades & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "FROM `" & Ruta + Archivo & "`.PREVISIONES PREVISIONES" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "WHERE (PREVISIONES.Fecha>{ts '" & Format(FechaInicio, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " 00:00:00'}" & _
        "And PREVISIONES.Fecha<{ts '" & Format(FechaFin, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " 00:00:00'})")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Previsiones"
    End With
    Call ActualizarPrevisiones
    wsPr.Cells.ClearFormats

End Sub
```

The Macro fails on the .CommandText line, i guess because im inserting all the propierties as one item, and each property should be 1 item. The thing is... how can I add there each item from my collection as an item of the array (won't be always the same amount of collecions).

I couldn't find anything else than creating an array from the scratch using a collection... But that's not what I want i believe.

Could someone give me a tip to keep going? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, just did the .CommandText without the Array, just everything there and It worked Like a charm... Thank you for reading anyway.